# Someone Can Help Me With This Warning Error! It Stuck My code

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to create an ERC20 token and if someone sends ether to this contract, contract will send equivalent tokens to the calling address.

Code:::

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "./new1ERC20.sol";

  contract ConfigureERC20 is new1ERC20 {

     uint256 tokenPrice = 500000000000000 wei;
     uint256 public tokensToGet = 0;

     fallback() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
     //   require(tokensRemaining > 0);
        tokensToGet = msg.value / tokenPrice;

        //_balances[] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
        //_balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].add(balance);
        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokensToGet);
        msg.sender.transfer(tokensToGet);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

[image: so]

Comment: 1. In that screenshot, the error-message hides some of your code (and worse - what appears to be the most relevant part of it). 2. Please post everything in plain copy/pastable text (no links or images). Also, please make sure that it is properly formatted (3 ticks at the beginning and 3 ticks at the end).

Comment: @goodvibration thanks, i'm new to this forum so please bear with me, i have edit it please check it now

Answer (score 0):

As @goodvibration mentioned you have failed to post the essential parts of the code.

Anyway, based on the error message you are most likely using the pre-0.6 style of defining a single fallback function like this:

`function() payable external { }` (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#fallback-function)

In Solidity version 0.6 the way of defining fallback functions was changed. There are now two separate functions: `receive` and `fallback` and their signature have changed - they are incompatible with pre-0.6 versions. So the function signatures are:

`fallback() external { }` and

`receive() external payable { }`

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/contracts.html#receive-ether-function

If you use Solidity version 0.6 or greater you can't use the old-style single fallback function anymore. So upgrade your code to conform to the new style and you should be ok.